# Detect duplicate variable with Laravel Collections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this collections of cart ecommerce items, I want detect that items have the same **article_id** value:

```
Collection {#306 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => CartLine {#294 ▼
      +cart_line_id: 836473
      +cart_id: 12957798
      +parent_line_id: null
      +quantity: 2
      +article_id: 1728
      +article_name: "TAZA CERAMICA"
      +data: ""
      +extradata: "{"original_dsn":"qF3Xxttr3B2w","tmp_dsn":"tmp_4k0k9q6usqd7pnu7d70rg0ta674zv8v4"}"
      +article_family_id: "AAAPTP"
      +article_on_line_v: 1
      +promotion_code: null
      +promotion_id: null
      +url_preview: "http://rp-static.pre/www_api/session_uploads/51_ddbc9b7fc849d214fb462f8af007c97c_6/836473/captura.jpg"
      +available_modify: true
      +model: ArticleModel {#295 ▶}
      +cession: 5.34
      +cession_original: 5.34
      +pvp: 9.95
      +pvp_original: 9.95
      +pvp_discount: 0.0
      +cession_discount: 0.0
      +discount_regularization: null
      +total_cession: 10.69
      +total_cession_original: 10.68
      +total_pvp: 19.9
      +total_pvp_original: 19.9
      #_READ_ONLY: []
      #_HIDDEN_FIELDS: []
      +__WARNINGS: []
    }
    1 => CartLine {#296 ▼
      +cart_line_id: 836474
      +cart_id: 12957798
      +parent_line_id: null
      +quantity: 1
      +article_id: 1728
      +article_name: "TAZA CERAMICA"
      +data: ""
      +extradata: "{"original_dsn":"59avc306wjem","tmp_dsn":"tmp_vnr16irux3ebi6pwy0dmn7ypeqwnr376"}"
      +article_family_id: "AAAPTP"
      +article_on_line_v: 1
      +promotion_code: null
      +promotion_id: null
      +url_preview: "http://rp-static.pre/www_api/session_uploads/51_ddbc9b7fc849d214fb462f8af007c97c_6/836474/captura.jpg"
      +available_modify: true
      +model: ArticleModel {#297 ▶}
      +cession: 5.34
      +cession_original: 5.34
      +pvp: 9.95
      +pvp_original: 9.95
      +pvp_discount: 0.0
      +cession_discount: 0.0
      +discount_regularization: null
      +total_cession: 5.34
      +total_cession_original: 5.34
      +total_pvp: 9.95
      +total_pvp_original: 9.95
      #_READ_ONLY: []
      #_HIDDEN_FIELDS: []
      +__WARNINGS: []
    }
    2 => CartLine {#298 ▼
      +cart_line_id: 836475
      +cart_id: 12957798
      +parent_line_id: null
      +quantity: 1
      +article_id: 1378
      +article_name: "JARRA CERVEZA ALEMANA"
      +data: ""
      +extradata: "{"original_dsn":"null","tmp_dsn":"tmp_8cu2ls6q18ip6vvd7qccrsbjiebgsrzj"}"
      +article_family_id: "AAAPTP"
      +article_on_line_v: 1
      +promotion_code: null
      +promotion_id: null
      +url_preview: "http://rp-static.pre/www_api/session_uploads/51_ddbc9b7fc849d214fb462f8af007c97c_6/836475/captura.jpg"
      +available_modify: true
      +model: ArticleModel {#299 ▶}
      +cession: 10.21
      +cession_original: 10.21
      +pvp: 19.0
      +pvp_original: 19.0
      +pvp_discount: 0.0
      +cession_discount: 0.0
      +discount_regularization: null
      +total_cession: 10.21
      +total_cession_original: 10.21
      +total_pvp: 19.0
      +total_pvp_original: 19.0
      #_READ_ONLY: []
      #_HIDDEN_FIELDS: []
      +__WARNINGS: []
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case, there are two items with same article_id value, 1728. I want get only the two items with this article_id.

After, I want add the articles_id 1728 quantities values, in only article 1728 item. In this case, I want get an unique article_id 1728 with quantity:2.

The final result that I want is this:

```
Collection {#310 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => CartLine {#294 ▼
      +cart_line_id: 836473
      +cart_id: 12957798
      +parent_line_id: null
      +quantity: 3
      +article_id: 1728
      +article_name: "TAZA CERAMICA"
      +data: ""
      +extradata: "{"original_dsn":"qF3Xxttr3B2w","tmp_dsn":"tmp_4k0k9q6usqd7pnu7d70rg0ta674zv8v4"}"
      +article_family_id: "AAAPTP"
      +article_on_line_v: 1
      +promotion_code: null
      +promotion_id: null
      +url_preview: "http://rp-static.pre/www_api/session_uploads/51_ddbc9b7fc849d214fb462f8af007c97c_6/836473/captura.jpg"
      +available_modify: true
      +model: ArticleModel {#295 ▶}
      +cession: 5.34
      +cession_original: 5.34
      +pvp: 9.95
      +pvp_original: 9.95
      +pvp_discount: 0.0
      +cession_discount: 0.0
      +discount_regularization: null
      +total_cession: 10.69
      +total_cession_original: 10.68
      +total_pvp: 19.9
      +total_pvp_original: 19.9
      #_READ_ONLY: []
      #_HIDDEN_FIELDS: []
      +__WARNINGS: []
    }
    2 => CartLine {#298 ▼
      +cart_line_id: 836475
      +cart_id: 12957798
      +parent_line_id: null
      +quantity: 1
      +article_id: 1378
      +article_name: "JARRA CERVEZA ALEMANA"
      +data: ""
      +extradata: "{"original_dsn":"null","tmp_dsn":"tmp_8cu2ls6q18ip6vvd7qccrsbjiebgsrzj"}"
      +article_family_id: "AAAPTP"
      +article_on_line_v: 1
      +promotion_code: null
      +promotion_id: null
      +url_preview: "http://rp-static.pre/www_api/session_uploads/51_ddbc9b7fc849d214fb462f8af007c97c_6/836475/captura.jpg"
      +available_modify: true
      +model: ArticleModel {#299 ▶}
      +cession: 10.21
      +cession_original: 10.21
      +pvp: 19.0
      +pvp_original: 19.0
      +pvp_discount: 0.0
      +cession_discount: 0.0
      +discount_regularization: null
      +total_cession: 10.21
      +total_cession_original: 10.21
      +total_pvp: 19.0
      +total_pvp_original: 19.0
      #_READ_ONLY: []
      #_HIDDEN_FIELDS: []
      +__WARNINGS: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: tried [`->unique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-unique) function?

Comment: Ok, now, I want add the articles_id 1728 quantities, in only article 1728 item. In this case, I want get an unique article_id 1728 with quantity:3.

Comment: ah I see you want to group them in one row and sum their quantity? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: surprisingly, Laravel's Collection had [orderBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-groupby) and [sum](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sum), perhaps you could use them @Antonio Morales.

Answer (score 0):

use groupBy and then map to return the calculated quantity for ex.

```
$collection = collect(); //your above collection
$finalCollection = $collection->groupBy('article_id')->map(function($items){
    $singleItem = $items->first();
    $singleItem->quantity = $items->count();
    return $singleItem;
});

// now in $finalCollection each item will be unique with article_id and it will have property named quantity which will have value equal to it's quantity.
```

Comment: Mmm this code return me the article 1728 unique, but not sum the quantities of all articles 1728, I want only article 1728 with quantity 3

Comment: make sure the CartLine can be assigned property 'quantity' you can check dd($items->count()); in closure and check you should be getting total quantity there but if quantity property is not assignable to CartLine class instance it won't work